# Paypal Future Payments: What HTTP requests do I send on the mobile device (Android)?

Tags: android, paypal

The Paypal Future Payments demo is pretty thorough, but I'm still a bit confused on what to send from the mobile application.

```
 private void sendAuthorizationToServer(final PayPalAuthorization authorization) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("auth",  authorization.toJSONObject());
    client.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment", params,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    Log.i("success:", String.valueOf(responseBody));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    Log.i("err:", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    );
```

What URL do i put

```
public void onFuturePaymentPurchasePressed(View pressed) {
    // Get the Client Metadata ID from the SDK
    String metadataId = PayPalConfiguration.getClientMetadataId(this);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("metaId",  metadataId);
    client.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment", params,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    Log.i("success:", String.valueOf(responseBody));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    Log.i("err:", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    );
}
```

I apologize if you feel this to be evident in the documentation. I have just been struggling for the past couple of days trying to find out what to put as the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `sendAuthorizationToServer()` should post the authorization response to your servers, NOT to PayPal servers.  Once the authorization response is received from your app, your server should do the token exchanges described [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#obtain-oauth2-tokens).  The resulting token(s) may then be used to create payments (for which your user has consented to) from your server.

At some point in the future when a purchase is initiated within your mobile app, your app should get `Client Metadata ID` and send it to your server for inclusion when creating the payment request, as described [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#create-a-payment-using-a-valid-access-token).

Hope this helps.